# JavaScript Prototype - Please Clarify

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Can someone please help me understand the prototype property? I don't understand whether the prototype property is a property of the function or of what's inside the function.

Let's say we create the following constructor, Food. At this point, the function Food() has the property Food.prototype. Since Food is an instance of Object, then this means that Obect.prototype is the prototype attribute of all objects created with Food().

```
function Food() {}
```

Then create another constructor Pizza. Pizza has the property Pizza.prototype.

```
function Pizza(toppings) {
    this.toppings = toppings;
}
```

Then we make Pizza inherit from Food by setting Pizza's prototype property to be an instance of Food. The prototype attribute of Pizza is now Food.prototype since Food is the parent of pizza.

```
Pizza.prototype = new Food();
```

Then we create an instance of Pizza

```
var myPizza = new Pizza("pepperoni");
```

Does myPizza also have a prototype property that it inherits from Pizza? If so, is myPizza.prototype == Object.prototype? What is Obejct.prototype? Is it a property of Object()? Do only functions have the prototype property? Is Object.prototype an object? Does Pizza.prototype refer to the entire function that creates the Pizza constructor? Is this function an object itself?

```
function Pizza(toppings) {
    this.toppings = toppings;
}
```

Or does the Pizza.prototype just refer to what is inside the scope of Pizza()?

```
this.toppings = toppings;
```

Is Pizza.toppings a property of Pizza.prototype? But isn't Pizza.prototype a property of Pizza()? Is toppings only a property of an object created with the Pizza constructor? And Pizza.prototype is a property of the Pizza constructor?

Current prototype chain is as follows:

myPizza --> Pizza.prototype --> Food.prototype --> Object.prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of starting with answers to the questions, I’m going to start with the way prototypes and constructors work to avoid confusion in trying to interpret those answers with partial understanding. So, prototype recap:

- Every value in JavaScript, except `null` and `undefined`, has an associated value: its prototype.¹
- The prototype is used to look up properties. When you evaluate `x.foo`, you check to see if the value `x` has an *own property* – a property on itself – named “foo”. If it does, `x.foo` is the value of that *own property*. If not, the lookup continues on `x`’s prototype.
- A value’s prototype can be `null`, meaning any property lookup that didn’t find an own property results in `undefined`.
- You can get a value’s prototype with the function [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).
- You can create a new object with a specific prototype with the function [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

*Constructors* in JavaScript have a *property named “prototype”*. The value of this property isn’t the prototype of the constructor; it’s the prototype of values created with the constructor. Taking your example constructor:

```
function Food() {}
```

If you run `new Food()`, a new object will be created with its prototype set to `Food.prototype`, and `Food` will be executed with `this` set to that new object. In other words, this:

```
// create a new instance of Food
let f = new Food();
```

means the same thing as this:

```
// create a new object with Food.prototype as its prototype
let f = Object.create(Food.prototype);

// initialize it using the constructor
Food.call(f);
```

Now, the way property lookups work, summarized above, gives rise to a prototype chain. If `x` has a prototype `y` and `y` has no prototype, `x.foo` gets looked up on this chain:

```
x -> y -> null
```

1. If `x` has an own property “foo”, `x.foo` evaluates to its value
2. If `y` has an own property “foo”, `x.foo` evaluates to its value
3. We’ve reached `null`, the end of the chain, so `x.foo` is `undefined`

The default value of the `prototype` property of constructors is a new `Object` instance, so the prototype chain of a `new Food()` looks like this:

```
f -> Food.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null
```

and you can say that a value `x` is an instance of a constructor `C` if `x`’s prototype is `C.prototype` or `x`’s prototype is not null and an instance of `C`. (If `x` *is* `C.prototype`, `x` is not an instance of `C`.) This is how the `instanceof` operator works²:

```js
console.log({} instanceof Object);  // true
console.log(Object.prototype instanceof Object);  // false
```

You can also say that `C` inherits from `D` if `C.prototype` is an instance of `D`.

Everything built into JavaScript has `Object.prototype` on its prototype chain. Functions are `Object` instances:

```
function f() {}
f instanceof Object  // true
```

and so constructors are too:

```
function Food() {}
Food instanceof Object  // true
```

It’s important to note that this doesn’t say anything about the relationship between instances of `Food` and `Object`. You can set `Food.prototype = null` to get `new Food() instanceof Object === false`, but it will still be the case that `Food instanceof Object`.

I hope that this framework is enough to address your questions. That was the idea, anyway. Still going to respond to them explicitly using it:

#### The questions at hand

> Let's say we create the following constructor, Food. At this point, the function Food() has the property Food.prototype. Since Food is an instance of Object, then this means that Obect.prototype is the prototype attribute of all objects created with Food().

All objects created with `new Food()` have a prototype of `Food.prototype`. The prototype of `Food.prototype` is `Object.prototype`. `Food` is a function, which means it’s true that it’s an instance of `Object`, but the relevant instance of `Object` here is `Food.prototype`.

> Then we make Pizza inherit from Food by setting Pizza's prototype property to be an instance of Food. The prototype attribute of Pizza is now Food.prototype since Food is the parent of pizza.

The prototype *property* of the function `Pizza` is now *an object with `Food.prototype` as its prototype*.

> Does myPizza also have a prototype property that it inherits from Pizza?

`myPizza` doesn’t inherit anything from `Pizza`. It inherits everything from the object `Pizza.prototype`. Since `Pizza.prototype` does not have a property named “prototype”, `myPizza` does not inherit a property named “prototype”.

> What is Object.prototype? Is it a property of Object()?

`Object.prototype` literally means “the ‘prototype’ property of `Object`”, so yes. This value is on the prototype chain of all instances of Object, which is only significant because most things in JavaScript are instances of Object. Apart from that, it’s like any other `prototype` property of a constructor.

> Do only functions have the prototype property?

Functions defined using the `function` or `class` keywords start with a property named `prototype`. (Arrow functions don’t, and can’t be used as constructors.) You can put a property named `prototype` on anything. It only has meaning when it’s on a constructor – a function used with `new` or `instanceof`.

> Is Object.prototype an object?

It’s an object with a lowercase “o”, when using “object” to refer to any non-primitive² value. It is not an instance of `Object` – it has a `null` prototype.

> Is this function an object itself?

Yes, functions are objects³.

> Does Pizza.prototype refer to the entire function that creates the Pizza constructor?

No. `Pizza.prototype` is not a function. It’s used by the `Pizza` constructor but the `Pizza` constructor is not an instance of it and was not created by it.

> Or does the Pizza.prototype just refer to what is inside the scope of Pizza()?

Nothing to do with scope, either. When you evaluate `new Pizza()`, `Pizza` is *called* with a new instance of `Pizza` as its `this` value. `this` is not the scope of a function. A “scope” is an area where some set of variables is visible.

```
function Foo() {
    let x = 5;  // a variable in scope. unrelated to `this`.
}
```

```
function Foo() {
    this.x = 5;  // assigning to a property of the value `this`.
                 // unrelated to variables.
}
```

> Is Pizza.toppings a property of Pizza.prototype?

It’s not `Pizza.toppings`. There’s a new object – `this` – and you’re assigning the value of a parameter to the `Pizza` function, named `toppings`, to a property of that new object, also named `toppings`. The new object’s prototype is `Pizza.prototype`, but the new object is not `Pizza.prototype` itself and so the answer is that “no”, `toppings` is not a property of `Pizza.prototype`.

> But isn't Pizza.prototype a property of Pizza()?

It’s a property of `Pizza`. (Just making sure `Pizza()` refers to the function and not the value you get by calling the function. Gotta be precise!)

> Is toppings only a property of an object created with the Pizza constructor?

Right!

> And Pizza.prototype is a property of the Pizza constructor?

Yes.

> Current prototype chain is as follows:
>
> myPizza --> Pizza.prototype --> Food.prototype --> Object.prototype

Also correct. You can confirm it with the aforementioned `getPrototypeOf`.

```js
Object.prototype.toString = function () { return 'Object.prototype'; };

function Food() {}
Food.prototype.toString = function () { return 'Food.prototype'; };

function Pizza(toppings) {
    this.toppings = toppings;
}

Pizza.prototype = Object.create(Food.prototype);
Pizza.prototype.toString = function () { return 'Pizza.prototype'; };

let myPizza = new Pizza();
myPizza.toString = function () { return 'myPizza'; };

let chainLink = myPizza;

while (true) {
    console.log(String(chainLink));
    
    if (chainLink === null) {
        break;
    }
    
    chainLink = Object.getPrototypeOf(chainLink);
}
```

Note that I’ve written `Object.create(Food.prototype)` instead of `new Food()` here. You don’t want to run the parent constructor outside the child constructor, though it was common in ES3. ES5 added `Object.create`. ES6 added `class` and `extends`, which is what you’ll want to use in practice.

<sub>¹ Primitives don’t have a [[Prototype]] in the spec but that doesn’t really matter because their property lookup and post-ES5 `Object.getPrototypeOf` work like they do.</sub>
<sub>² Primitives are strings, booleans, numbers, symbols, `null`, and `undefined`. Primitives are immutable – they don’t have any own properties. The distinction between objects and primitives isn’t that important in JavaScript, but because they don’t have any own properties it doesn’t make sense to use them as prototypes. They also don’t count as `instanceof` anything for what I’m going to claim are historical reasons.</sub>
<sub>³ By default, that is. You can ask one or all of them not to be with `Object.setPrototypeOf`. There’s no reason to do this.</sub>